# OpenLayers 2, JSON vector through WFS

Tags: geoserver, wfs, openlayers-2, json

Consider this example,

https://geoext.github.io/geoext2/examples/grid/feature-grid.html

It uses

```
protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "../data/summits.json",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            })
```

for the locations and elevations of some mountains. There are three properties: name (string), height (long), and geometry (point).

What I want to do is put the json file onto GeoServer and call it that way. I imported the file into GeoServer, and I know it works because I can see it with a WFS url. But I'm trying to load it with the code

```
var vecLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vector", {
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        'default': style
    }),
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed() ],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        readFormat: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON(),
        url: "http://fakeurl.com/geoserver/wfs",
        srsName: "EPSG:4326",
        featureNS: "http://fakeurl.com/geoext/geonodeuri",
        featureType: "summits",
        outputFormat: "json",
        version: "1.1.0"
   })
});
```

I know that `url`, `featureNS`, and `featureType` are all correct because I can successfully add other shapefile vectors in the same workspace with them. I'm quite stumped as far as getting the WFS protocol to work, however. Do I need to set `geometryName` or something? GeoServer lists three properties, and I need all three of them. Ideally I would get the exact same result as the simple `OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP` protocol.

---

If I put the JSON file in a web directory and do an HTTP protocol to it, it works. Which is to say,

```
protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "http://fakeurl/data/summits.json",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            })
```

displays just fine. However, when I link to a WFS Getfeature request, like

```
protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "http://fakeurl/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=geonode:summits&maxFeatures=50",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            })
```

I get no result. But the url provided displays the JSON file in a browser. I don't understand. I just want some way of getting those contents via GeoServer, but it continues to elude me.

---

turns out there's something wrong with the layer itself. I can view the JSON data through a link but only if I'm logged into Geoserver. If I'm not logged in, then I get a "Could not find layer" message. So I guess that's my issue: why data imported in GeoServer it not made public (my JSON), but a layer through Geonode is.

Comment: I would guess that the easiest fix is to forget json and wipe away the outputformat line for letting GeoServer to send data in the default GML format. See the OL2 WFS examples, for example http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/wfs-filter.js.

Comment: I converted the JSON file into a GML formatted xml file, and loaded it directly with the HTTP protocol --  it works fine. Then I tried to use the default GeoServer WFS protocol and still nothing is shown. I have to assume that the WFS protocol and the HTTP protocol are not taking in the information in the same way.

Comment: Alright, problem solved. I'd installed a package called geoserver-geonode. A security "feature" of the package makes it so only layers uploaded through GeoNode can be served up. Since I imported the JSON file through GeoServer's import extension, it was not allowed to be served. 

So I installed GeoServer and GeoNode packages separately and all is fine. (I also removed the JSON formatting and just went with the default GML format, as suggested.)

Comment: WFS isn't a protocol

Comment: RE: WFS protocol, I was referring to the OpenLayers code

`protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, problem solved. I'd installed a package called geoserver-geonode. A security "feature" of the package makes it so only layers uploaded through GeoNode can be served up. Since I imported the JSON file through GeoServer's import extension, it was not allowed to be served. So I installed GeoServer and GeoNode packages separately and all is fine. (I also removed the JSON formatting and just went with the default GML format, as suggested.)